# How does this React code work on CodePen even if no preprocessor is selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codepen

I have this code on CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdOyJX
that works perfectly, and I am confused about why this works.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>Hello, world!</div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In the JavaScript settings, there is no preprocessor selected, so I expect the JSX syntax to fail as "<" is an invalid token.
What makes this work on CodePen?

Comment: This does not explain why this code may work. `<div>Hello, world!</div>` is not a correct JS syntax, and without a transpiler (or a codepen preprocessor) that should not even be parsed correctly.

Comment: There is some JSX pre-processing going on as the result = > `ReactDOM.render(
React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello, world!'),
document.getElementById('root'));
//# sourceURL=pen.js`

Comment: Looks like codepen, if no JS pre-processor is selected, is using Babel as default.  eg.  using `async / await` get all the `_asyncToGenerator` stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Keith. Is this documented anywhere? What is the purpose of selecting Babel then in the preprocessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your Pen now, it looks like it does indeed fail on the `<` in your JavaScript, but if you turn Babel on, it works well.

Babel must have been accidentally turned on my default back when you asked this question!

Answer (score 0):

CodePen added Babel support automatically as stated [here](https://blog.codepen.io/2015/05/19/babel-now-on-codepen-write-es6-javascript-and-react-jsx/).

Comment: The article you mentioned states that you should select Babel as a JS preprocessor. There is no mention that Babel is selected automatically if you do not select any preprocessor (like in the CodePen of the question).